# Looking for a Counterxample: Is a multivariate convex function decreasing "above" its point of maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}^d \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a twice continuously differentiable function (assume infinite differentiability, if you want), such that $\nabla f(\mathbf{0}) = 0$ and $\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{0})$ is a (strictly) negative definite matrix. In my case, the matrix $\nabla^2 f(\mathbf{0})$ is diagonal, with strictly negative diagonal entries. Then, is the following statement true?

**Statement:** There exists $R > 0$, such that if $0\leq x_1,\ldots,x_d,y_1,\ldots,y_d \leq R$ and $x_i \leq y_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq d$, then
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_d) \geq f(y_1,\ldots,y_d)~.$$

**My attempt:** Since $\nabla^2 f$ is continuous, it also remains strictly negative definite in a small neighborhood of $N$ of $\mathbf{0}$ (and hence, $f$ is strictly concave on $N$). Now, by the two-term Taylor expansion, I have:
$$f(\mathbf{y}) - f(\mathbf{x}) \leq \nabla f(\mathbf{x})^\top (\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x})~.$$
So, I would be done, if I can show that $\nabla f(\mathbf{x}) \leq 0$ (entry-wise) for all $\mathbf{x} \in N$. Although it seems that this follows easily by going to second derivatives, something prevents me from doing this. I need that the mixed partials are also non-positive in another small neighborhood of $\mathbf{0}$, which does not follow from the continuity of $\nabla^2 f$, since its non-diagonal entries are exactly $0$.

Is the above conjecture at all true? I would be happy if someone gives me a counterexample.

Comment: Did you apply the mean value theorem for vector-valued functions (here $\nabla f(x)$)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions